# Car Radio with Android

Tags: usb, pc, android

I'm searching for a Car Radio with Android as a complete system. The Car Radio should support USB-Debugging via the PC.
Is there such a Car Radio?
Thanks.

Comment: Do I even want to know why you want this?

Comment: I certainly do :-) This is giving me ideas. I want a radio where I can add apps that I code myself. Mwuuuuuuuuhahahhahaha!!!

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica that's exactly what I want! :)